# "The wait operation timed out" after 120secs of CREATE INDEX called from SMO TransferData method

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, timeout, sqlconnection, smo

Recently created a C# tool using SMO class to automate the refactor and merge of SQL Server databases for migration into Azure.

The TransferData method successfully adheres to the BulkCopyTimeout for the data copy phase; proved this by extending it when it timed out.

When the transfer phase moves to CREATE INDEX statements they appear to hit a timeout after 120sec / 2mins on a particularly large table.

The ServerConnection object has  StatementTimeout and ConnectionTimeout both set to 0 (as initial research suggested doing) to no avail.

Running a profiler trace, I noticed the "Application Name" differs from the original set (MergeDB v1.8) when the bulk copy and index create phases are running.

The original connection is still present but it appears that the Transfer class spawns additional connections (but whilst appearing to pass on BulkCopyTimeout; failing to pass on the application name and (my hypothesis) the StatementTimeout property.

I'm using SMO v150.18131.0 connecting to SQL 2008 R2.

[image][image]

Comment: I suspect this could be a bug and have also posted the situation here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38059711-smo-transferdata-method-spawns-new-connection-with

Comment: I've also created a test harness to isolate the issue and set StatementTimeout and ConnectionTimeout to values lower than 120s (60s) and the timeout still occurred after 120s.  Other index creation queries complete successfully in the sub 120s.